# looking how to code for a pop up message "No records found"

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

I wrote a search function in my software when the search result is zero. Its not giving me any pop up windows or any message. How to deal with this situation My code is as below.

I need any message to be pop up, the moment it shows no data from my table.

```
      `private void cncInfoBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
        this.Validate();
        this.cncInfoBindingSource.EndEdit();
        this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.cncDataSet1);

       }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'cncDataSet1.CncInfo' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        this.cncInfoTableAdapter.Fill(this.cncDataSet1.CncInfo);
        timer1.Start();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.cncInfoBindingSource.AddNew();
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Validate();
        this.cncInfoBindingSource.EndEdit();
        this.tableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(this.cncDataSet1);
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.cncInfoBindingSource.RemoveCurrent();
    }
    int count = 0;
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            count = cncInfoBindingSource.Count;
            label_status.Text = "Records Found: " + count.ToString();
            if (count < 2)
            {
                Next_btn.Visible = false;
                Previous_btn.Visible = false;
            }
            else if (count <= 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("No records found ");
            }
            else
            {
                Next_btn.Visible = true;
                Previous_btn.Visible = true;
            }

    }

    private void Next_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cncInfoBindingSource.MoveNext();
    }

    private void Previous_btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cncInfoBindingSource.MovePrevious();
    }
    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.cncInfoTableAdapter.SearchFileName(this.cncDataSet1.CncInfo, textBox1.Text);
    }
    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        this.cncInfoTableAdapter.SearchFileName(this.cncDataSet1.CncInfo, textBox1.Text);

    }
            }
          }
           `
```

Comment: Is this c or is it c#?

Comment: This is not C, as C doesn't have properties and events. Please use proper tags for the question you're posting.

Comment: Would also like more information on the timer, its settings, and why the heck you are using it.

Answer (score 1):

It's pretty ugly to show message box on timer.

However, to the problem you asked for help:

your code is: if (count < 2) { /*hide buttons*/} else if (count <= 0) {/*show message*/}

The message box will never be showed, because 0 < 2 and the code just hides the buttons.

Comment: @david carpenter where I have to give this code. Where I should call this

Comment: You can just change the order: first the block for less or equal to zero, after that less than two, and at the end the rest.

Comment: @david  int count = 0;
     private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
     count = cncInfoBindingSource.Count;
    label_status.Text = "Records Found: " + count.ToString();
    if (cncInfoTableAdapter.GetData().Rows.Count < 1)
    {
    MessageBox.Show("whatever");
    Next_btn.Visible = false;
    Previous_btn.Visible = false;
    }
    else if (count < 2)
    {
    Next_btn.Visible = false;
     Previous_btn.Visible = false;
     }
     else
     {
     Next_btn.Visible = true;
     Previous_btn.Visible = true;
     }
      }

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
if(cncInfoTableAdapter.GetData().Rows.Count < 1) MessageBox.Show("whatever");
```

Comment: didn't compile? or didn't do anything?

Comment: it complied. But no result. I mean its still the same. No message coming

Comment: You probably have it in the wrong method, place breakpoints in all your methods be clicking on the left of the editor window (Where the line numbers are or would be if enabled) to set a breakpoint.

Comment: Or simply remove the if statement to make sure that the method is being executed.

Comment: When I gave like below code, its showing the message  . But its keep on showing when ever I press the search button.`                   if                   (cncInfoTableAdapter.GetData().count < 1)
          {
              MessageBox.Show("whatever");
              Next_btn.Visible = false;
              Previous_btn.Visible = false;
          } `

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that

Comment: When I changed the code to if `      (cncInfoTableAdapter.GetData                 ().count< 1) MessageBox.Show("whatever");
              Next_btn.Visible = false;
              Previous_btn.Visible = false; } Its working. I mean the message box what ever is popping up. But its popping up for count>1 also. How to deal with this

Comment: I can't just do your homework for you. Learn to use the debugger, you'll need to sooner or later anyways

Comment: ok tell me where I can find that.. is that the debugging present in debug button